# Bind multiple TextBoxes to one struct in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, struct

How do i bind two TextBox objects to a [System.Windows.Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.aspx) **struct**?
The binding only has to work in this direction:

(textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text) => (Size)

After a user inserts the width and height in the TextBoxes on the UI the Size object should be created.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox_Width" Text="{Binding ???}" />
<TextBox Name="textBox_Height" Text="{Binding ???}" />
```

C#:

```
private Size size
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit:** Size is a struct! Therefore "someObject.Size.Width = 123" does not work. I need to call the Size-Constructor and set someObject.Size = newSize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you not just expose 2 properties - width and height from your model, along with a size property. The width and height would appear in your {Binding} expressions, and then when you want to get the size property, it initialises based on these two fields.

Eg, your model might be something like;

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Width{ get; set; }
    public int Height{ get; set; }

    public Size Size{ get{ return new Size( Width, Height ); }}
};
```

Hope this helps.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

*Window1.xaml.cs*:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Size",
        typeof(Size),
        typeof(Window1));

    public Size Size
    {
        get { return (Size)GetValue(SizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        _button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_button_Click);
    }

    void _button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Size.ToString());
    }
}
```

*Window1.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Size.Width}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Size.Height}"/>
        <Button x:Name="_button">Show Size</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```